# np.array ndmin argument: specify placement of added dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an M-dimensional `np.ndarray`, where `M <= N`. Beyond this condition, the array may have any shape. I want to convert this array to N-dimensional, with dimensions 0 through M kept the same and dimensions M through N set to 1.

I can almost accomplish this behavior by copying the array using `np.array` and supplying the the `ndmin` argument. However, this places extra axis to the 'first' rather than 'last' positions:

```
>>> a3d = np.zeros((2,3,4))
>>> a5d = np.array(a3d, ndmin = 5)
>>> a5d.shape
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4) #actual shape
(2, 3, 4, 1, 1) #desired shape
```

Is there a way to specify where the added dimensions should go? Is there an alternate function I can use here which can result in my desired output?

Obviously in the example above I could manipulate the array after the fact to put axes in the order I want them, but since the orignal array could have had anywhere from 0 to 5 dimensions (and I want to keep original dimensions in the original order), I can't think of a way to do that without a tedious series of checks on the original shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `.reshape` ...

```
>>> a3d = a3d.reshape(a3d.shape + (1, 1))
>>> a3d.shape
(2, 3, 4, 1, 1)
```

If you want to pad up to a certain dimensionality:

```
>>> a3d = np.zeros((2,3,4))
>>> ndim = 5
>>> padded_shape = (a3d.shape + (1,)*ndim)[:ndim]
>>> new_a3d = a3d.reshape(padded_shape)
>>> new_a3d.shape
(2, 3, 4, 1, 1)
```

Comment: The second part of this works well, clever! Padding up to a certain dimensionality is exactly the goal here, so the first part wouldn't work in this particular case.

Comment: @Joe -- You could also combine my answer with Gadi's -- `a3d.shape = padded_shape`, though I'm not sure you really gain too much by that.

Comment: I usually do this as `... + (1,)*(ndim - a3d.ndim)`, but the end result is the same.

Comment: @Jaime -- Yep.  That's probably even a little more elegant.  I just didn't feel like thinking :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just set

```
 a5d = np.array(a3d)
 a5d.shape = a3d.shape + (1, 1)
 print a5d.shape

 (2, 3, 4, 1, 1)
```

since the arrays are of the same physical size

Comment: The issue with this approach is that my original array might have already been 5 dimensional. If the shape is already `(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`, this won't work.